# Julian Date Between VB.Net and Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, vb.net

I want to convert a date to Julian date in VB.Net (1.1) and regenerate this as gregorian date using objective-C, and the revers is posible (Julian from objective-C and gregorian date in VB.ne)

Comment: I don't know how I can do this calculations

Comment: what is the format of your input dates? how are the dates represented?

Comment: I want to move dates between Objective-C and VB.Net, VB.Net and Objective-C as Numbers and Convert this Numbers to actual dates

Comment: where have you been stuck? cannot you convert the dates to numbers/strings? or numbers/strings to dates or where? I still don't see the problem, because you've described the process in you comment. are you not able to implement it? do you want someone else makes the code for you? what do you expect honestly?

Comment: I found a solution, how I can publish it here?